# Can I make my app open another app AND click a button in it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Let's say there is a pre-existing Android app on my phone that has a button on its home screen that I can click. I know there is a way to launch that app from an app I am creating, but is there a way to click the button as well automatically? Is there a parameter I can pass in, and how would I go about using it?

Comment: No. You can pass "parameters" to another activity (or application), but as long a the receiving activity is not coded to respond to that parameter with a button click (and a pre-existing app would normally not be coded that way), there is no way to make it do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have your apps push a button on another app. That would be a giantic security leak.

However, the other app might have options on how to call it. It will depend on that other app. You would call the other app with an Intent, then use [`putExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) to provide extra parameters.

Comment: come on, how [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rise.automatic.autoclicker.clicker&hl=en&gl=US) was built then?
I researched a lot but no luck(

Comment: @ErgashMasharipov Any luck finding how auto clicker apps work?