# Android open another app and click on button

Tags: android

I want to know is there a way to open another app and click on some button. In my case, I need to open play market application from my app(using intent) and click on "update" button.

It would be great to have a method like `findViewById` which I can use while I am in another app.

Comment: @Suaro thanks, but I know how to open another app. The problem is where I need to click a button inside this app programmatically.

Comment: The second app is yours? If the application is yours, you may be able to send a message in the intent so that the other application knows what to do.

Comment: If the app is not yours, you should have some method enabled so that when you perform that interaction, it will send a response to your app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348782/can-i-make-my-app-open-another-app-and-click-a-button-in-it

Comment: Unless the second app is also yours, that sounds like potential malware and a major security risk. So it is not possible for security reasons.