# A background app to click on a specific pixels and back button on a third-party foreground app

Tags: android-intent, onclicklistener

I need to develop an android app which will open another app (not developed by me) and then click on specific pixels and back button. I can open the other app using Intent. How to perform clicks on the newly opened app?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348782/can-i-make-my-app-open-another-app-and-click-a-button-in-it) asked whether we can click on a specific button of another app and as I can guess, that's not possible. What about clicking on a specific pixel? If a human can click on a specific pixel, why not an app developed by a human?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make my app open another app AND click a button in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348782/can-i-make-my-app-open-another-app-and-click-a-button-in-it)

Comment: @KenY-N That question deals with clicking button. I need to know whether it's possible to click on a specific pixel. If a human can click on a specific pixel, why not another app?